# The UK's policy on time left on passport for non-EU citizens?

Tags: visas, uk, passports, canadian-citizens

Additional info: I am Canadian, going for a 1-week leisure trip, and have never before had trouble at the UK border.

Otherwise phrased: Will I be allowed into the UK with a passport has 5.5 months left?

*[sorry if this has already been answered, I did look :$]*

Comment: They use a curtailment formula if the passport has less than 6 months remaining (if they notice the expiry date at all).

Comment: @GayotFow Can you expand on "curtailment formula" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk, your passport "must be valid for the whole of your stay."

I suppose the border officer might be forced to stamp you in for a shorter period than the standard six months, but aside from some irritation resulting from that, it seems unlikely that you will have any problem.